# Qual é o motivo de se utilizar DbMigration em CodeFirst?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Qual é o objetivo de se utilizar DbMigration quando se está desenvolvendo um projeto utilizando CodeFirst? Utiliza-lo é uma boa prática, ou é algo que não causa grandes impactos na implementação e/ou manutenção do sistema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***O que DbMigration?***

Representa a classe base para migrações baseada em código. *Entity Framework Migrações APIs* não são projetados para aceitar a entrada fornecida por fontes não confiáveis ​​(como o usuário final de uma aplicação). Se a entrada for aceita a partir de tais fontes que devem ser validados antes de serem passados ​​para essas APIs para proteger contra ataques de injeção SQL, etc. (*MSDN Microsoft, DbMigration Class. 2014. Disponível em: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration(v=vs.113).aspx. Acesso em: 22.jun.2014, tradução site google*)

Além da funcionalidade trivial de modificações nas suas Entidades, tem um caráter de proteção como relatado em tradução logo acima. Quando se projeta algo novo, e começa o seu desenvolvimento pelas classes de entidades, o DbMigration assume a responsabilidade de fazer essas alterações e proteger o seu código de usuário final. Isso é importante mediante invasões e os famosos ataques de injeção de SQL.

***Objetivo:***

O principal objetivo são as alterações que o seu projeto vai solicitando no decorrer da programação, desde uma simples adição de um propriedade, uma coleção, até a adição de chaves estrangeiras, primárias e no atual <sup>**6+**</sup> índices.

*Exemplo:*

Você começou o seu model por uma classe `Carro` como modelo apresentando abaixo:

```
[Table("Carros")]
public class Carro
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarroId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Logo após criou a sua classe `Db` que herda de `DbContext` (*Entity Framework 6+*):

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public Db()
        :base("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cboNew0001;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha") 
    { }
    public DbSet<Carro> Carro { get; set; }
}
```

Bom até esse momento não temos a base criada nem a tabela, então, como devo proceder com essa criação do banco e da respectiva tabela.

No Package Manager Console digite: `enable-migrations` e pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será criado um arquivo dentro da pasta **Migrations** com o nome de `Configuration`.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ConsoleApplication6.Db>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        //AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }    
    protected override void Seed(ConsoleApplication6.Db context) { }
}
```

Perceba que a configuração `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;` coloque `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` para que fique habilitado as modificações da sua base
Volte novamente Package Manager Console e digite add-migration e um nome qualquer exemplo

```
add-migration newdb
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E com isso é criado um classe assim:

```
public partial class newdb : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Carros",
            c => new
                {
                    CarroId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Descricao = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CarroId);
        
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Carros");
    }
}
```

Mas, ainda não tivemos a geração do modelo físico (a base e a tabela) só temos um modelo conceitual. Como proceder:

Novamente ao Package Manager Console e digite: `update-database` e pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao mostrar nenhum erro na tela, e aparecer essa mensagem:

```
Applying explicit migrations: [201406221524303_newdb].
Applying explicit migration: 201406221524303_newdb.
Running Seed method.
```

Foi criado o seu banco e a tabela Carros como figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom até ai tudo bem, mas, agora queremos adicionar um campo a mais nessa `class` Carros para que ela fique assim:

```
[Table("Carros")]
public class Carro
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarroId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    //NEW CAMPO
    public int? Ano { get; set; }
}
```

**Aonde eu mudo na base ou pelo código?**

Agora é tudo pelo código, fazemos os passos a seguir

```
add-migrations newcodigo
```

ele vai criar um outro aquivo assim:

```
public partial class newcodigo : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Carros", "Ano", c => c.Int());
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Carros", "Ano");
    }
}
```

perceba que é a a adição de uma nova columa com o nome de Ano igual foi proposto no modelo conceitual e para confirmar as alterações digite:

```
update-database
```

e pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd> sua base fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Boa prática:***

É essencial pelo motivo, `CodeFirst` e não fica preso em tecnologia de Sistemas Gerenciadores de Banco de Dados (SGBD), trazendo o conforto da codificação somente no Visual Studio.

Comment: Existe algum momento em que é necessário alterar o código do DBMigration gerado automaticamente pelo Entity Framework?

Comment: Não... Eu pelos nunca precisei

Answer (score 2):

## Qual é o objetivo de se utilizar `DbMigration` quando se está desenvolvendo um projeto utilizando Code First?

Os objetivos são não depender tecnologicamente de um banco de dados e não controlar manualmente o histórico de modificações desse banco.

Ao desenvolver sua aplicação, criando, alterando ou excluindo *Models*, o *framework* se encarrega de gerar as alterações que serão necessárias no banco de dados para que o sistema funcione. O objetivo é deixar o desenvolvimento o mais agnóstico possível no tocante ao banco de dados.

## Utiliza-lo é uma boa prática, ou é algo que não causa grandes impactos na implementação e/ou manutenção do sistema?

Sim, é uma excelente prática, justamente porque retira a responsabilidade do desenvolvedor de ter que atualizar o banco toda vez que o código da aplicação é modificado.

A manutenção desse banco de dados se torna trivial, visto que cada Migration possui as instruções de modificação necessárias para a etapa em que o sistema a ser publicado se encontra.

Na implementação, recomenda-se usar a configuração de migrações automáticas, visto que o código dos *Models* muda o tempo todo. Já quando o sistema é publicado em produção, a configuração recomendada é a de migrações manuais, com o código mais controlado.